# Common vs Ground in DC Circuit

Tags: switches

I am trying to wire up a DSP controller. It has 2 limit switches, and the instructions say to connect the "COM" on both switches together and the "NO" to y- and x-. There is an indicator light on the controller to show when the switch(es) are activated. When the switch(es) is/are activated, the light on the controller does light; However, the stepper motors do NOT stop moving when the switch is activated.

Wouldn't "Common" and "Ground" be the same thing? Any ideas?

Comment: I addressed your misunderstanding about COM and ground. But to answer about your actual application it would help if you can give: datasheet of the DSP controller, datasheet of the limit switches, details of how the stepper motors relate to the electronics, and a schematic diagram of your circuit.

Answer (score 8):

When talking about switches, "COM" is not at all the same as ground. It's the "common" input/output to the switch. The "NO" or normally open terminal is disconnected from COM when the switch is inactive, and connected when the switch is active. The "NC" or normally-closed terminal is connected to COM when the switch is inactive and disconnected when the switch is active.

In this diagram L1 is the NC terminal, L2 is the NO terminal, and COM is the common terminal:

[image: public domain image from Wikimedia]

The only reason to connect COM to ground is if you want to switch the other terminals to be connected or disconnected to ground.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but it's worth a mention that there's a brief period where the COM pin is left floating, as the switch changes. It's usually worth using a pull-down or pull-up resistor to prevent unexpected behavior.

Comment: For future reference, it's worth knowing that what @Polynomial describes is called "break-before-make" operation, and it's not guaranteed for all switch types.

Answer (score 2):

"Common" and "ground" are different and should not be conflated. "Common" is a point of reference shared throughout a circuit, typically the node in reference to which every other node is described. In the case of a single-pole double-throw (SPDT) switch, common (also called the pole) is the terminal which the "normally open" and "normally closed" terminals switch to.

"Ground", on the other hand, is *the earth*. Common and ground are frequently tied together, but it's easily possible to have a circuit wherein tying common to ground would cause a ground loop, or even catastrophic failure.